# How to improve Swift performance with streaming buffers?

Tags: objective-c, performance, swift

Say I want to process a large document with Swift. The whole file won't fit into memory, so we'll have to use streaming. In Swift we have access to `NSInputStream`, however once the input is transferred to a Swift String, and consumed, performance goes bad rapidly. Say I want to read a buffer (1024 bytes), and create Swift Strings from those, and then iterate over the string to get to the individual characters. I'll show piece-by-piece the performance degradation as extra statements are added.

```
var stream = NSInputStream(URL: input)!
stream.open()
var buffer = [UInt8](count: 1024, repeatedValue: 0)
```

Only reading the stream processes at ~200 MB/s:

```
while stream.hasBytesAvailable {
    let readSize = stream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
}
```

Creating NSString from the buffers at ~130 MB/s:

```
while stream.hasBytesAvailable {
    let readSize = stream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
    let nsString = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: readSize, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
```

Casting from NSString to String at ~90 MB/s:

```
while stream.hasBytesAvailable {
    let readSize = stream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
    let nsString = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: readSize, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let swiftString = nsString as String
}
```

Iterating over the String at ~1 MB/s:

```
while stream.hasBytesAvailable {
    let readSize = stream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
    let nsString = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: readSize, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let swiftString = nsString as String
    for character in swiftString { }
}
```

Why is this code running this slow? Now I understand that in the current state of affairs the hybrid mix of Objective C and Swift a lot of (implicit) casting is going on. However the biggest performance hit appears to be iterating over the Swift String itself.

Note that the code was run with compile flag Fastest [-O].